# Navigation Menus Depth for specific menus

Tags: menus, wp-admin, navigation

I know that's possible to limit the depth that navigation menu items can be given children like this:

```
wp_add_inline_script('nav-menu', 'wpNavMenu.options.globalMaxDepth = 1;', 'after');
```

My issue is that I have three menus, and I only want to limit the depth on two of them. Is it possible to conditionally add the above when particular menus are being administered?

Limiting the depth displayed when actually rendering the menus in my theme is a last resort. I'd rather have the menu created in admin match the menu actually shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to know which menu is selected, you can do that in JavaScript

```
    var selected_menu_id = $("#select-menu-to-edit option:selected").prop("value");

    if ("56" === selected_menu_id) {
        wpNavMenu.options.globalMaxDepth = 2;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a good approach, however I'd prefer to to have to rely on the menu's ID as that is bound to differ between environments.

Comment: How do you define which menu must have this depth restriction if it's not by ID ?

Comment: Using `wp_get_nav_menu_object` with the ID retrieved is working well. Thank you.